# Uber Universal Deep Link giving CORS error

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to develop with universal deep links. When the user has the Uber app installed, everything works as expected. But if not, the user ends up at a page with "Open in the Uber app" and "Download Uber" links, both of which do nothing. In the console, a CORS error is reported. This includes opening the "[example universal deep link to Uber HQ](https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff%5Bformatted_address%5D=Uber%20HQ%2C%20Market%20Street%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2C%20USA&dropoff%5Blatitude%5D=37.775231&dropoff%5Blongitude%5D=-122.417528&_ga=2.260097860.830846417.1581952272-1919070024.1581952272)" given in the developer docs. Is this a known issue or is there something I can do to work around it? I'd like my users to be able to use the deep link without this poor experience.

[image: console CORS error]

Request headers (for ul-min.a36a5e.js):

```
GET /web-mobile-client/js/ul-min.a36a5e.js HTTP/1.1
Host: d34odocr7rsfu1.cloudfront.net
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: https://m.uber.com
Sec-Fetch-Dest: script
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Moto Z (2)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.99 Mobile Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff%5Bformatted_address%5D=Uber%20HQ%2C%20Market%20Street%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2C%20USA&dropoff%5Blatitude%5D=37.775231&dropoff%5Blongitude%5D=-122.417528&_ga=2.28187893.830846417.1581952272-1919070024.1581952272
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8
```

Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2020 17:29:53 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 c66a9c8f31dcbd61d052f66d50b6d87c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: LAX3-C1
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 00Y21qP41BPYaywzR6BHA0BC-5ctAe03xFKBgOBgDKupwlaN-2IzLA==
```